# How to fetch column from table and make it a link in repeater?

Tags: .net, database, repeater

I develop a table in sql server 2008

Table is as follow

Table name: tbqst(tablequestion)

Columns: 
         qstcod(question code)

```
     qstdsp(question description)
     qstsubby(question submitted by)
     qstdat(question date)
     qstans(question answer)
```

Now i added 4 records manually in this table.

Now i need output as:

q.1 what is asp.net?(this is ques. description of 1st question)

q.2 what is vb.net ?(this is ques. description of 2nd question)

q.3 what is sql?    (this is ques. description of 3rd question)

q.4 what is oracle? (this is ques. description of 4th question)

Also these questions should act as links
When i click on any question, it should display

1) question description of the question clicked.

2) qstans i.e. question answer that i enter manually in table

3) qstsubby

4) qstdat

Also, when i again click on particular question,the contents displayed should get collapsed and similarly for all the 4 questions.

And kept in mind that i can use only REPEATER for this problem.

Plz help me......
Any help is appreciated

Comment: So, uh, despite the horrible formatting... what is your actual issue? Where are you having trouble? Where's your current code?

Answer (score 0):

You seem already to have a solution to your problem, using the repeater. Bind the datatable to your repeater and use template your rows with in  element
Then you could use javascript to show/hide the answer section